# scrapy crawl a set of links that might contains next pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to:

1. Extract links for a certain page
2. For each link, I need some contents for that **link**, and the contents of 'next pages' of that link.
3. Then export it as json file(not important as far as I think regarding my problem)

Currently my spider is like this:

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     ...
    def parse(self, response):
        for url in someurls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_next)

    def parse_next(self, response):
        for selector in someselectors:
            yield { 'contents':...,
                     ...}
        nextPage = obtainNextPage()
        if nextPage:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_next)
```

**The problem is for a set of links that the spider processed, the spider could only reach 'next page' for the last link of that set of links**, I viewed that through *selenium + chromedriver*. For example, I have 10 links(from No.1 to No.10), my spider could only get the next pages for the No.10 link. I don't know if the problem occurred was because of some structural problem of my spider. Below is the full code:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


class BaiduSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'baidu'
    allowed_domains = ['baidu.com']
    start_urls = ['http://tieba.baidu.com']
    main_url = 'http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%E5%B4%94%E6%B0%B8%E5%85%83&ie=utf-8'
    username = ""
    password = ""

    def __init__(self, username=username, password=password):
        #options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #options.add_argument('headless')
        #options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()#chrome_options=options)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    # checked
    def logIn(self):
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#com_userbar > ul > li.u_login > div > a')
        elem.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#TANGRAM__PSP_10__footerULoginBtn')))
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TANGRAM__PSP_10__footerULoginBtn')
        elem.click()
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TANGRAM__PSP_10__userName')
        elem.send_keys(self.username)
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TANGRAM__PSP_10__password')
        elem.send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TANGRAM__PSP_10__submit').click()
    # basic checked
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.logIn()
        # wait for hand input verify code
        time.sleep(15)
        self.driver.get('http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%E5%B4%94%E6%B0%B8%E5%85%83&ie=utf-8')
        for url in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.j_th_tit')[:2]:
            #new_url = response.urljoin(url)
            new_url = url.get_attribute("href")
            yield scrapy.Request(url=new_url, callback=self.parse_next)
    # checked
    def pageScroll(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
        SCROLL_LENGTH = 1200
        page_height = int(self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
        scrollPosition = 0
        while scrollPosition < page_height:
            scrollPosition = scrollPosition + SCROLL_LENGTH
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(scrollPosition) + ");")
            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        time.sleep(1.2)

    def parse_next(self, response):
        self.log('I visited ' + response.url)
        self.pageScroll(response.url)

        for sel in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.l_post.j_l_post.l_post_bright'):
            name = sel.find_element_by_css_selector('.d_name').text
            try:
                content = sel.find_element_by_css_selector('.j_d_post_content').text
            except: content = ''

            try: reply = sel.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.j_lzl_m_w').text
            except: reply = ''
            yield {'name': name, 'content': content, 'reply': reply}

        #follow to next page

        next_sel = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("下一页")
        next_url_name = next_sel.text

        if next_sel and next_url_name == '下一页':
            next_url = next_sel.get_attribute('href')

            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse_next)
```

**Thanks for your help, and welcome any suggestions referring my code above**

Comment: Are you manually selecting the next button? It doesn't look like that is needed. Have you checked out this article: http://edmundmartin.com/scraping-baidu-with-python/

Comment: @Zev yes, "下一页" part is where I selecting the next button, I looked into that article, but it's actually not related

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? 2 has some weird stuff with Unicode, don't know if it's relevant with scrapy though.

Comment: @RobRose using python3

Comment: At this moment Im crawling a set of 1 million datasheet from a manufacture using selenium on my macbook pro, and its a pain in the ars since Im creating a new chrome object for each URL since its a Tree. I just found a simple way to handle this using https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser or even using mechanize it kills my RAM...!!! dont use selenium for web crawling for ajax sites.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to scraping content from one page, store it, and allow the spider to continue the crawl to the scrape and store items on subsequent pages. You should be configuring your items.py file with the item names and pass the items through each scrapy.Request using a meta.

You should check out https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1138

To illustrate how this works, it goes something like this...
1. First, we set up the item.py file with the total items to be scraped on every page.

```
#items.py
import scrapy

class ScrapyProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    page_one_item = scrapy.Field()
    page_two_item = scrapy.Field()
    page_three_item = scrapy.Field()
```

Then its importing the items.py item class to you scrapy spider.

```
from scrapyproject.items import ScrapyProjectItem
```

The in your scraper, through each page iteration that has content you want, its initializing the items.py class the pass the items using 'meta' to the next request.

```
#spider.py
def parse(self, response):
    # Initializing the item class
    item = ScrapyProjectItem()
    # Itemizing the... item lol
    item['page_one_item'] = response.css("etcetc::").extract() # set desired attribute
    # Here we pass the items to the next concurrent request
    for url in someurls: # Theres a million ways to skin a cat, dont know your exact use case.
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                             callback=self.parse_next, meta={'item': item})

def parse_next(self, response):
    # We load the meta from the previous request
    item = response.meta['item']
    # We itemize
    item['page_two_item'] = response.css("etcetc::").extract()
    # We pass meta again to next request
    for url in someurls:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                             callback=self.parse_again, meta={'item': item})

def parse_again(self, response):
    # We load the meta from the previous request
    item = response.meta['item']
    # We itemize
    item['page_three_item'] = response.css("etcetc::").extract()
    # We pass meta again to next request
    for url in someurls:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                             callback=self.parse_again, meta={'item': item})
    # At the end of each iteration of the crawl loop we can yield the result
    yield item
```

As to the problem about crawler only reaching the last link, I would like to have more info instead of guessing what the problem could be. In your "parse_next", you should add a "print(response.url)" to see if the pages are being reached at all?  Im sorry if I didnt understand your problem and wasted everyones time lol.

## EDIT

I think I understand better you issue ... You have a list of urls, and each urls has its own set of urls yes?

In your code, the "obtainNextPage()" might be the issue? I have in the past when encountering this type of case have had to use some xpath and/or regex magic to properly obtain the next pages. Im not sure what "obtainNextPage" is doing but... have you thought of parsing the content and use selector to find the next page?? For example.

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     ...
    def parse(self, response):
        for url in someurls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_next)

    def parse_next(self, response):
        for selector in someselectors:
            yield { 'contents':...,
                     ...}
        #nextPage = obtainNextPage()
        next_page = response.xpath('//path/to/nextbutton/orPage'):
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page),
                                 callback=self.parse_next)
```

You should still add that "print(response.url)" to see if the url thats being requested is being called correctly, might be urljoin issue.

Comment: Good answer given the question. However, I would recommend `self.logger.debug` rather than `print`, and the OP should read https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html

Comment: You're absolutely right on that. That would be the proper way to debug what's going on. Using print is just a hacky way to quickly asses, in this case, what the response URLs are looking like.